# JPA 2.0, hibernate 3.5, jars & persistence.xml location

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0, persistence.xml

I'm building a desktop application using hibernate 3.5 & JPA 2.0.

I have 2 jars,

the lib, which defines every entity and DAO, packages looks like this :

```
org.my.package.models
org.my.package.models.dao
org.my.package.models.utils
```

In org.my.package.utils I defined my hibernate utility class for getting  EM & EMF instances, which means the lib is bound to a Persistence Unit name but that's not a problem for now (anyway you can recommend me a better way to manage that)

the second jar is built as follow:

org.my.package.app

META-INF is defined on the root of the project which means in my jar I can find this directories directly in the root:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/persistence.xml
org/
org/my/
...
org/my/package/app/Main.class
```

When I run the app, hibernate doesn't managed to find persistence.xml it throws an exception something like "package or class for PersistenceUnitName not found".

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.11 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
3 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.5.0-Final
25 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.0-Final
28 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
33 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
41 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
153 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.0-Final
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at Main.main(Main.java:171)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PMMPU] class or package not found
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1316)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1094)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:981)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:359)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
        at dil.tal.polymarmots.utils.HibernateUtil.getEmf(HibernateUtil.java:45)
        at dil.tal.polymarmots.utils.HibernateUtil.getEm(HibernateUtil.java:54)
        at dil.tal.polymarmots.utils.HibernateUtil.getMotDAOImpl(HibernateUtil.java:115)
        at dil.tal.polymarmots.models.Mot.<clinit>(Mot.java:30)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.Extrait
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1232)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1304)
        ... 11 more
```

I googled a bit about [the problem](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/06/where-to-put-persistencexml-in-web-app.html) but I can't get the source code organisation right.

Any help ?

Comment: are you sure the message means the file is not found, rather than a problem within the file?

Comment: Post the **exact** exception (and trace) and your persistence.xml

Comment: http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=155

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *class or package not found* message is self-explaining: a class or a package is not found - not the `persistence.xml` - as suggested by the cause of the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: model.Extrait
```

The `model.Extrait` entity doesn't reflect the packaging you're showing but it is very likely declared in your `persistence.xml` (that you're not showing) but not present on the class path.

Comment: This error helped me to understand that I didn't understand Java Exceptions output...

Comment: @phmr We all learn from mistakes :) Some call succession of mistakes "experience".

Comment: Pascal, if that saying is true, then I have a lot of experience.  Found a bug in my code that was bothering the heck out of me thanks to this answer.

Comment: I just want to correct my previous comment: «I was not reading Java Exceptions». I discovered recently while learning js and scheme that **reading** exceptions is a significant part of learning to code in a language.